# How to create grid of 3D cubes like WeatherCube?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, 3d

I recently downloaded [Weathercube](http://www.weathercube.com) for iOS, and was pleasantly surprised by its UI.

As a primarily `UIKit` (2d, simple interface) iOS developer, I'm not quite sure how to go about creating a similar interface.

I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me how to create a UI that consists of a grid of tiles (e.g. 2x3, like Weathercube), that perform a 3D rotation, giving the appearance of multiple cube-faces per tile.

*NOTE:
I'm only interested in mimicking this part of the interface, and not the rest of the cube-feel that links `ViewControllers` as a 3D interface.*

Here's an example from the Weathercube app, where a tap on a tile causes it to rotate between either a weather symbol or a corresponding description (i.e. 2 cube faces):

[image]

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290721/3d-rotatable-cube-with-clickable-areas-on-sides

Comment: How so? The question you're referring to wishes to create a single cube in a 3D space, whereas I'm looking for a pseudo-3D cube based on a 2D tile-grid.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out our implementation of exactly this over at Chupamobile:
http://www.chupamobile.com/products/details/2106/Cube+Selector/

It's gesture-based, fully featured, ready to use out of the box - and pretty much exactly what you want